# Magento 2 Create Custom module

Tags: module, magento2

I have search many times, with key code "create module magento 2". 
Can you help me more link is exactly what I should be doing to create a module with magento 2. 
I have tried follow example in this [Link](http://blog.magestore.com/how-to-create-a-simple-module-in-magento-2-0/)  but it not work.

Have any for: 
rewrite Event "Observer";
Custom Template. 
or more.

Comment: the link content shows module creation in magento 1.* and not of magento2

Comment: and here is a proper link : https://www.ashsmith.io/2014/12/simple-magento2-controller-module/ I tried the same key code that you have used !!!

Comment: @RajeevKTomy it link follow 2 example, 1 for magenton 1.*, 2 for magento 2

Comment: If you are familiar with Magento 1 module development, this is a good start: [Building Magento 2 Extensions 101 for Magento 1 Developers](http://de.slideshare.net/mzeis/building-magento-2-extensions-101-for-magento-1-developers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can recommend you as a study this [sample module](https://github.com/tzyganu/Magento2SampleModule) I've created some time ago. Not sure if it works on the latest versions, but it's a place to start.
I also started a [module creator for Magento 2](https://github.com/UltimateModuleCreator/Umc_Base). This is in the dev phase for now and it only allows you to create backend CRUD modules, but frontend and others will follow (sooner or later).

Comment: thank's very much.

Answer (score 4):

Further to what @Marius has suggested, you will probably benefit from reading the [Magento 2 Dev Docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/). Specifically the [architecture](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/architecture/bk-architecture.html) and [module](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/architecture/modules/mod_intro.html) sections. The Magento 2 documentation is significantly better than Magento 1.

Comment: for observers try etc/events.xml 
    <event name="event_name">
        <observer name="your_observer_name" instance="Dist\ModuleName\Model\Observer" method="yourMethod" shared="true|false" />
    </event>